# Android Contacts Group changes

Tags: android

I have two contacts group on my device like `Work`, `Home`. I have to add  contact on that particular group. Like `Add john(Contacts name0) to Work group`.

I have used following Code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                       Integer.parseInt(contactId));
                values.put(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID,
                        "3");
                values
                        .put(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

              context.getContentResolver().insert(
                       ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

But I get the following output: `content://com.android.contacts/data/714`

Please guide me, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong! What makes you think something is wrong?

Looks like you're trying to add the group identified by "3" for the raw contact identified by contactId. The result is contactId now belongs to group "3" (You have to look up "3" in ContactsContract.Groups).

What this does is add a GroupMembership row to the Data table. Group membership is an attribute of the raw contact contactId. So you've done what you set out to do. The result is an Uri that points to the data row you added.

I figure you were expecting something else. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks John, I have to add John(Contacts name of my device) in Work ("3" is Group raw id of Work group)group Which is  already in my home Group.Please Can u suggest me which uri i have used instead of ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI..